# Saving URL content with javascript and pass it to PHP as variable

Tags: php, javascript

I want to save the url content of some website with javascript (from a client side) and pass it over
as a variable to my php file, it's ok that the javascript will be in the php file.

is there a way to do so?

Comment: any reason why you don't want to use [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)? Are you wanting to save hashbangs?

Comment: Yea because I want to see what the client get not the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from javascript to php you have to use form submit, change url including query parameters, or ajax